# How do i stop ViewController from flickering when using present in swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I am very new to swift and I am having trouble creating my project. I have two View Controllers one with a button which when pressed plays a video. When the video finishes I have code that automatically takes it to a new View controller. but as it does that you can (for a millisecond) see the original view controller. I have turned off all animations but I can still see it. Is there a way to stop this? Am I building the project in the wrong way? As I said I am new to swift and only have a little knowledge in HTML and CSS so any help would be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let movieURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")!
        let player = AVPlayer(url: movieURL as URL)

        playerViewController.player = player
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerViewController.player?.currentItem)

        self.present(playerViewController, animated: false) {
            self.playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
    }


    @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {


        self.playerViewController.dismiss(animated: false)


        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

        self.present(secondVC, animated:false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it does not take the fullscreen. Starting from iOS 13, the default presentation is not the fullscreen. So, you will need to set the `modalPresentationStyle` UIViewController's property with UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

instead of:

```
self.present(secondVC, animated:false)
```

use:

> ```
>     secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
>     self.present(secondVC, animated:false)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip that works great. Do you have any idea how to stop the flickering when you transition from the first view controller and second?

Comment: You are welcome. We should edit the `modalPresentationStyle` property of the `secondVC` not the `playerViewController`.

Comment: @user2655836 Please if it's the correct answer for your question, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: thanks for the response, but the flickering still exists so the question/problem isnt fixed. if you have any thoughts please let me know.

Comment: Setting the `modalPresentationStyle` property determines the presentation style of the view controller that would be presented. So to stop flickering when transitioning to secondVC, set the `modalPresentationStyle` of the `secondVC` with `.fullScreen`

Comment: Thanks I've added .fullscreen  but the flicker is still there. As the video closes you see the first view controller background and then a split second afterward it loads into the second viewcontroller.